# Product Loop User asked how many Product Most Expensive

Tags: java

I am having a time with this program. Would someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? The Program prompts the user to enter the number of products in the product catalog. The program should then prompt the user for the name and the price of each product in the product catalog. Once all of the products have been entered, the program should output the product information (name and price) of the most expensive product in the catalog. Your solution to keep track of the product with the highest price.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductTester
{
    private static final String price = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Products: ");
        int count = in.nextInt();
        int name = 1;
        int item = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the Name of Product " + item + " :\n");
            String name1 = in.toString();
            System.out.print("Enter the Price of Product " + item + " :");
            int price = in.nextInt();

            item++;
        }
        System.out.println("Product = " + name + "$ " + price);
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it asks me how many times and when I put it in both of the questions come up and I am unable to enter anything,  Actually, the Product question is suppose to come up first and then the price question.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are reading the input wrong:

This line:

```
String name1 = in.toString();
```

Should be:

```
String name1 = in.next();
```

By calling `in.toString()` you are calling the method that will returns the string representation of this `Scanner`. This method is overwritten from the `Object` class that is the parent class for all classes in Java and usually is used for debugging purposes.

When you call `in.next()` you will read the next `String` token in the `Scanner`'s input stream.

Secondly, you are not using the `name1` variable or the `int price` variable inside your loop.

For this part:

> The program should then prompt the user for the name and the price of each product in the product catalog.

Right now, all you are doing is creating variable `name1` and `price` inside your loop and not using them for anything. In your last print statement, the `name` and `price` that are printed are the values you assign at the beginning of your program.

```
// the values shown bellow are printed

// ...
private static final String price = null;
// ...
int name = 1;
// ...
```

So your program will always print:

```
Product = 1$ null
```

You should just delete the `final static String price` variable because there isn't any real purpose to it.

For storing products, you might want to use an object from the Java Collection such as an `ArrayList`. To do that, you should create a class called `Product` that holds the product name and price and then you build a list of them.

```
class Product {
    String name;
    int price;
}
```

This would be a better, cleaner, object-oriented approach to your problem. However, you can also keep track of the biggest price and product name in two variables (as it seems your plan was) so I will show you how to do that.

> Once all of the products have been entered, the program should output the product information (name and price) of the most expensive product in the catalog.

So, you can use two variables, `String expProdName` and `int expProdPrice` to keep track of the most expensive product's information. You also need two temporary variables, `String currProdName` and `int currProdPrice` to obtain the current entered information from the user.

Inside your loop, you are using the variable `item` to print the order of products but you can just use the loop counter `i` to do that.

You should initialize the `expProdPrice`, which is the most expensive price thus far, to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which is the lowest possible integer value so that comparing with new prices is certain to find the max price. However, considering prices of products shouldn't be negative, you can also initialize it to -1.

Then inside your loop, each time you read a new price, you compare it to the value stored in `expProdPrice` and if it is larger, you update the most expensive price to this new price.
You also need to update the product name.

Let's see how the code will look:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of Products: ");
    int count = in.nextInt();

    String expProdName = ""; // expensive product name
    int expProdPrice = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // expensive product price

    String currProdName = ""; // current product name
    int currProdPrice = -1; // current product price

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the Name of Product " + i + " :\n");
        currProdName = in.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the Price of Product " + i + " :\n");
        currProdPrice = in.nextInt();

        // if current price larger that the most expensive price thus far
        // update the most expensive price to the current price and
        // update the name of the most expensive product to current product's name
        if(currProdPrice > expProdPrice) { 
            expProdPrice = currProdPrice;
            expProdName = currProdName; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nMost expensive product is:\n\nProduct name:\t" + expProdName + 
                       "\nProduct price:\t" + expProdPrice + "$");
}
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong but I also a logic error is where I have the system.out.print("..."): where I had price as its variable it actually should be something else and not the variable for my price question.

Comment: I see where I was going wrong.  I changed in.next(); for my product line. And I need to change a couple other things, But this is one of those times where I feel like I should just shoot myself.  I should of known that. Hey, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here

`String name1 = in.toString();<-- you do not read anything from the console` 
                                    `you just convert Scanner to String which
                                    does not make sense at all`

change to

```
String name1 = in.next(); <-- reads one token which is type
                               String from System.in for you
```

> The **java.util.Scanner.next()** method finds and returns the next
>   complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and
>   followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may
>   block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation
>   of hasNext() returned true.

[read more about next()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm)

Comment: Yes, I actually fixed that.  Thank you.  I am trying to figure out how to get most expensive calculation.  The problem I am running into is that my price variable is only one. for the risk of sounding stupid, I need to figure out another way. To get the most expensive.

Comment: I am suppose to have an output that will show the Most expensive product after the prices are plugged in after being asked.